# How to generate Excel charts show per interval?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following mathematical function (I am not referring to any programming language, just simply math):

```
F(X)={ 1/4, X∈(0,1]
      5/12, X∈(1,2]
      9/12, X∈(2,3]
     11/12, X∈(3,4]
}
```

I want to show the output of this formula as a chart in Excel like this:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1):

If the intervals are uniform in width you can use a plain old column chart, and set gap width to 0 so there is no gap between the bars. Unfortunately Excel centers labels under each bar, not between them.

If they are integers >=0, you can use an area chart, as follows.

Set up the data like this:

[image: Area Chart Data]

Make an area chart, which will look like the first chart below. Even though you only have X values of 0 through 4, these are repeated, because area charts treat each occurance as a different category.

Convert the category (horizontal) axis to a date-scale axis. In 2007, format the axis, and check the box for a Time Axis. In 2003, go to Chart menu > Chart Options > Axes tab, and check the Time-Scale option. Now it looks like the second chart below.

Excel applied a date format to the date axis. Change the number format of the axis to General, and it looks like the third chart below.

[image: Area Chart Construction Sequence]

Comment: these steps don't work for me, I please you that ,if you want,  make a video recording,my chart appears different than yours. Thank you